# Troubleshooting tools/techniques for network connectivity in Windows

Tags: windows-10, internet-connection

Recently, my Windows 10 laptop has been getting poor network connectivity lately. In particular, I get disconnected from online games and this seems to happen every now and then at about a few times a day. I am trying to figure out what the cause is, as the problem could be in any one of the following:
- Applications that I am running (the game itself, and/or firewalls)
- Hardware/physical damage
- Firmwire/device drivers
- Incorrect configuration of some system setting in Windows
- Incorrect configuration of some system setting in my BIOS
- Incorrect configuration of my router
- Signal interference from nearby wireless devices
- Issues at the ISP's end (I am at a university, using the university's wifi)

I'm not entirely sure how to go about systematically figuring out where exactly the problem is. I doubt it is at the ISP's end, since others using the same wifi do not seem to experience any issues. What are some useful resources, tools, and techniques I might use to track down the source of the problem? If this isn't the right place to ask, where should I ask? I'm willing to provide any needed details.

Comment: Using university wifi for gaming? Stop. That sounds painful.

Comment: ??????????????????????????????????

Comment: Unless the sysadmin for the university owes you a HUGE favour, there is nothing at all you can do to improve your situation.

Comment: I am trying to determine the source of the problem. I cannot be certain at this point that the ISP is the issue. If the problem is on my end, I'd like to take the steps to fix it. Is this not clear in the original question?

Comment: You are on a network which you have no control over. Please understand this. There is absolutely nothing you can do unless you work for the university IT department. You need to accept this and move on. The university needs to open specific ports on their router's firewall and give you a fixed IP, then lay rj45 cable direct to your location.

Comment: What makes you certain there is no problem with my hardware based on the little information I've provided?

Comment: Because you are using a wifi connection you have no control over. The first thing you do is open up specific ports for your device, the second thing you do is have an ethernet cable to your machine, and then if you still have problems then, and only then - can you start looking at your hardware.

Answer (score 0):

With gaming, an ethernet connection is far more suitable - and you need access to the router. You have neither so there isn't anything you can do in this situation.